# How can I use STUFF in a JOIN to append data to a column, grab DISTINCT values and order by DESC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What I'm trying to do is find all related records. Problem is, it seems I can only get the third related record and nothing past it. We have records that can have 5+ dependents.

Here is my initial query

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
field1 varchar(25),
field2 varchar(50))

insert into #Data (field1, field2)
VALUES ('02968365','05431590'),
('02968365','05431590'),
('04355059','04460576'),
('04355059','05339398'),
('04460576','04776412'),
('04512483','04983582'),
('04512483','05434032'),
('04561297','05482964'),
('04561297','04801903'),
('04776412','05339398'),
('04801903','05482964'),
('04844609','05431253'),
('04844609','05431253'),
('04983582','05434032')


select distinct 
       rtrim(d1.field1) field1,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '/' + rtrim(d2.field2)
         from #Data d2
         where d1.field1 = d2.field1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') field2
FROM #Data d1
```

And here is what the query produces:

```
        field1       field2               
______________________________
   1  | 02968365  |  /05431590
   2  | 04355059  |  /04460576/05339398
   3  | 04460576  |  /04776412
   4  | 04512483  |  /04983582/05434032
   5  | 04561297  |  /04801903/05482964
   6  | 04776412  |  /05339398
   7  | 04801903  |  /05482964
   8  | 04844609  |  /05431253
   9  | 04983582  |  /05434032
```

These are the rows that are related

**2, 3, 6** 
- 04460576 in row 2 field2 connects to 04460576 in row 3 field1, 04776412 row 3 field2 connects to 04776412 field1 in row 6

**4, 9**
- 04983582 in row 4 field2 connects to 04983582 row 9 field 1

**5, 7**
-- 04801903 in row 5 field2 connects to 04801903 in row 7 field1

What I'm needing this to is connect those records that are still related **or** remove them from the list if they are connected in field2 column.

This is what I'm looking for. I'm hoping to get them sorted as shown:

```
        field1       field2               
______________________________
   1  | 02968365  |  /05431590
   2  | 04355059  |  /04460576/04776412/05339398
   3  | 04512483  |  /04983582/05434032
   4  | 04561297  |  /04801903/05482964
   5  | 04844609  |  /05431253
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Use a recursive cte?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a recursive CTE approach like below
<kbd>**[See demo here](http://rextester.com/BSAWHX55201)**</kbd>

```
; with selfJoined as 
(
select 
    field1=rtrim(d1.field1) ,
    field2=rtrim(d1.field2)
from #data d1 left join #data d2 
    on d1.field1=d2.field2
where d2.field1 is null
   union all
select 
    field1=c.field1,
    field2=rtrim(d2.field2)
from selfJoined c join #data d2 on rtrim(d2.field1)=c.field2
 )

, output as 
(
    select 
    distinct 
       field1,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '/' + field2
         from selfJoined s2
         where s.field1 = s2.field1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') field2
FROM selfJoined s
  )
select * from output
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Works good. I tested it with additional data in it and unfortunately it doesn't work for the data I entered. See here example here: http://rextester.com/edit/BSAWHX55201. Any idea how that can be fixed?